# how to skip first row and add heading to download csv file

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    functionExport(json_data, "User_Report", true);

    function functionExport(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
        var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
        var CSV = '';
        if (ShowLabel) {
            var row = "";
            for (var index in arrData[0]) {
                row += index.toUpperCase() + ',';
            }
            row = row.slice(0, -1);

            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }
        //1st loop is to extract each row
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            var row = "";
            for (var index in arrData[i]) {
                row += '"' + $('<div>').html(arrData[i][index]).text() + '",';

            }
            row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }
        if (CSV == '') {
            alert("Invalid data");
            return;
        }
        //Generate a file name
        var fileName = "Manage_";

        fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = uri;
        //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".csv";
        //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how to skip first row and add(pass) heading to download csv file

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion, don't reinvent the wheel. CSV's have a lot of gotcha's. Just use a library that already exists, papaparse.

Here's the function to take a JSON object and turn it into a CSV:
http://papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv

If you want to skip the first row, just pass `arrData.slice(1)` to it instead of `arrData`

If you want to add your own headers, that's what the third function signature is for... like this: `Papa.unparse({fields:['a','b','c'],data:arrData})`

Comment: i didn't getting what your saying... i want to  add heading (Manage User) in first row of download csv file, after that i want to display data in next row

Comment: Do you understand how to load the external library?
If you load it, this statement gives a csv, with the first row skipped, and with customized headings: `csv = Papa.unparse({fields:['a','b','c'],data:arrData.slice(1)})`

Comment: or even...
csv = "Some string\n"+Papa.unparse(arrData.slice(1))

Comment: right after the one that sets arrData. Though it seems that you are not actually using the csv string in the end of your code at all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing i in your first loop to 1?
Also, your jQuery selector should be $('div')

```
for (var i = 1; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + $('<div>').html(arrData[i][index]).text() + '",';

        }
        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }
```

Comment: ...it's your code with the changes: i = 1 and $('div')